# Filter duplicate rows in powerbi table based on language

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, filtering

I have the following table in Power BI:

| index | id | language | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | fi | value_in_fi |
| 2 | 312 | fi | value_in_fi |
| 3 | 312 | en | value_in_en |
| 4 | 312 | se | value_in_se |
| 5 | 22 | fi | value_in_fi |
| 6 | 1 | se | value_in_se |
| 7 | 22 | en | value_in_en |

I would like to filter out rows from the table where the id appears more than once, under the following conditions:

If the row's language is "fi," keep that row. If the language "fi" is not found, keep the language "en." If neither is found, keep the language "se." So, the resulting rows in the table would be 1, 2, 5, 6.

Is there any way to do filtering like this? I'm kind of new to powerbi so haven't succeeded in this so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply some additional transformation on your table. Here below is the **Power Query** code for your table. Go to **Advance Editor** of your table and use this below code-

Don't forget to change the **previous_step_name** in line 1 of the new code.

```
let
    //.... your existing code

    //New code starts here    
    #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"previous_step_name", "Custom", each if [language] = "fi" then 1 else if [language] = "en" then 2 else if [language] = "se" then 3 else 4),
    #"grouped_table" = Table.Group(#"Added custom", {"id"}, {{"min", each List.Min([Custom]), type number}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added custom", {"id", "Custom"}, #"grouped_table", {"id", "min"}, "grouped_table", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"grouped_table", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here is the output-

[image]

---

Your new code will be like below-

```
let 
    Source = PostgreSQL.Database("localhost", "test"), 
    table_name = Source{[Schema="testschema",Item="table_name"]}[Data], 


    //New code starts here    
    #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"table_name", "Custom", each if [language] = "fi" then 1 else if [language] = "en" then 2 else if [language] = "se" then 3 else 4),
    #"grouped_table" = Table.Group(#"Added custom", {"id"}, {{"min", each List.Min([Custom]), type number}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added custom", {"id", "Custom"}, #"grouped_table", {"id", "min"}, "grouped_table", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"grouped_table", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Please accept the answer and put an up vote if it worked for you :)

Comment: So if my original code in advanced editor looks like this: 
```
let
  
    Source = PostgreSQL.Database("localhost", "test"),
    table_name = Source{[Schema="testschema",Item="table_name"]}[Data]
in
    table_name
```
Should I put it like this to the part where the old code goes and also should the previous_step_name in this situation be "table_name" ?

Comment: @Lurri, you can check the lower part of my updated answer.

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick, Thank You!